# Retrieve MSI product code for an installed Service

Tags: c#, powershell, windows-installer

I've looked around a fair amount for an answer to this, hopefully my "google-fu" is not the issue...anyhow.

I want to enumerate all the services on a Windows (2003 R2, 2008, 2008 R2) machine and then determine what their product codes are to determine what MSI Package (in our maintained repository) was used to install that Windows Service).

Basically, take the list that comes from something like this PS command: {Get-Service | Format-List *}, or the C# line: System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController[] services = ServiceController.GetServices();, and then iterate over all those returned service names and determine what the MSI Product Code is for each.

I'd prefer the C# route, but will take all suggestions.

Is this possible?  Or is there a better way that does not involve the ServiceController class in my example?

Thanks in advance for any advice!

Comment: There is no link between a service name and an MSI product code. Even disregarding the fact that you could potentially have services that were installed without using the Installer Service at all, once a product is installed there is nothing in the OS that tracks a specific file back to a specific product GUID.

Comment: Well actually I suppose that isn't entirely correct. If you have the physical MSIs that did the installation, you could open those up and search the files table for the specific exe/dll/whatever that the service is running then in a backwards sort of way work out what product did the install. Again...assuming the service was the result of a Windows Installer package to begin with.

Answer (score 3):

WiX DTF's Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller has a class called ComponentInstallation. It has a static property called AllComponents that returns an IEnumerable of ComponentInstallation.

I suppose you could query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services to get the imagepath and try to correlate it to a Component that is managed by MSI.  Once you make that connection the ComponentInstallation class has a property called ClientProducts that returns IEnumerable of ProductInstallation.   Remember, a component can be shared across multiple MSI's.

Once you have the ProductInstallation reference you can get it's ProductCode property.

This would catch the services that were installed by MSI even if they were using InstallUtil because you are tracking who laid down the file.

Answer (score 2):

Not all Windows Services are installed using a MSI.  You can install a .NET service using installutil.exe.  Windows Services are registered in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services`. As the registry does not hold MSI product numbers, I think you would need to get the `ImagePath` property and cross reference that items installed by the MSI package.  The MSI data is stored in `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Installer`.  How to link these two up is beyond me.

Comment: Without cracking open each and every MSI and iterating over the files table, there is no link.